# C# and sqlite basics

Tags: c#, sqlite

How to connect, create DB, use it in VS08 (05 or 10 will be ok)? (Vsualy better not writting lots of code=))
need for
tutorials
libs
blogArticles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Answer (score 3):

[Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SQLiteCSharp.aspx) article all nicely wrapped up for you.