# What kind of database for a small WPF app that offers search speed and deployment ease?

Tags: wpf, xml, database, ms-access, sql-server-ce

I have a database of approximately 8,000 records. Each record has 1 text field (300 chars max) and about 20 numeric fields.

Operations on this database are mostly read-only: search and sort. No updating.

For my **WPF app**, 
I like XML because it is simple to deploy but the text search is somewhat slow because I do a search on every keystroke entered on the search textbox. My current considerations are: XML, Microsoft Access, SQLCE.

**What (other) database technologies should I consider and what would you choose for speed and ease of deployment?** Thanks.

Comment: Postgre SQL is a good free alternative, unlike access and other free db's, it can be server based rather than file based, will give the best performance

Comment: I would choose SQL Server Compact for speed and ease of deployment: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one advantage of using JET is of course all versions of windows since windows 98SE have a copy installed. This means no installing of the data engine is required.

And such an engine is fast and such file based data engines tend to be much faster than SQL server or any server based engine in which you usually are forced to talk to that system through a network socket layer even when running local.

And regardless of often being forced to go through a network layer, you are working though a transaction log and "ACID" database architecture with roll back etc. So tons of additional memory, additional processing and there almost always an extra file layer you "suck" data through for transactions. All in all these things add up to more memory, more processing and really much get in your way when such features are not required.

A file based data engine like JET when used without a network tends to run circles around the huge transaction based server editions of SQL, MySql or whatever.

So the JET database engine still is not a bad choice since you don't have to install it on your target computer. All of the other suggestions here require distribution issues and that of installing issues.

So some bonus parts are:

- So no install required, been installed on all windows for 12+ years
- Lighter weight and less software layers between your code and the data on disk.
- Small memory foot print
- Non service architecture and thus the code runs "in process" and thus no inter application communication occurs to slow down reading
  of data (to be fair, some of this is ActiveX).
- You not forced to communicate through a network socket.
- You can use some indexing commands with JET and some options are available which even allow you to by-pass using SQL.
- On your development box you can fire up MS-access to manage and work on those data tables.

Answer (score 2):

See whether the answer to this previous Stack Over question sparks your interest: [How to work with SQLite in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932013/how-to-work-with-sqlite-in-wpf)

SQLite itself is easy to deploy.  For those read-only operations with the small database you mentioned, my guess is performance will be fine.

The only issue which made me reluctant to propose this as an answer was uncertainty about how well it would integrate with WPF.  However, I did a quick web search (for wpf and sqlite), and found that Stack Overflow link I included above; and there are a lot more.  Unfortunately I'm not a WPF guy so don't know how useful they will be.

One criticism I've heard about SQLite is that's is not good for concurrent multi-user operations.  Since you were considering SQLCE, perhaps that won't be a limitation for you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about speed but as for ease of deployment and development I'll recommend SQLite + Fluent NHibernate.
NHibernate is the best ORM for .net now. With Fluent Mappings it allow not to write boring mappings classes, but do auto-mapping and it's really easy to configure.

As for database you can choose from SQLite and SQLCE and I'll recommend you the first one. Haven't worked much with SQLCE cause it has nasty limit: string row must be no longer then 4k chars... Another big advantage of SQLite: it can provide in-memory DataBase which is really helpful for testing.
If you'll have any questions - please ask.

Answer (score 1):

My vote would be slightly for SQLCE over JET. The main reason for that is if you wanted to use entity framework or LINQ I don’t think that is possible with JET but it is easy with SQLCE.

If those are not problems for you then Albert has made some very valid points and JET is still a good option

Comment: Much agree. The other part of SQLCE is support of replication to SQL server, and this does open up some interesting possibliies for off line data mode and not really have to write much code to accomplish a sync (assuming some type of sync with a server is required here).